# WNetOpenEnum does not return anything after root level

Tags: c#, c++, windows, winapi, networking

I have a C# code which enumerates through network neighborhood using WNetOpenEnum & WNetEnumResource. This does return "Microsoft Terminal Services", "Microsoft Windows Network" and "Web Client Network", but does not return anything for the Microsoft Windows Network level in Windows 10.

I can see connected shares in my Windows Explorer though. Problem is also described in this question, but there are no much answers - https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/6b2120f6-523e-4705-9231-fd19f05611eb/wnetopenenum-wont-enumerate-past-the-root-level-error-1231?forum=windowssdk

Looks like WNetOpenEnum does not work properly in Windows 10 anymore. How can I replace it? What Windows Explorer uses to show Network shares?

I read about NetUseEnum function, but there is a remark about it in MSDN

> This function applies only to the Server Message Block (LAN Manager
> Workstation) client. The NetUseEnum function does not support
> Distributed File System (DFS) shares. To enumerate shares using a
> different network provider (WebDAV or a DFS share, for example), use
> the WNetOpenEnum, WNetEnumResource, and WNetCloseEnum functions.

Comment: With [this sample](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/wnet/enumerating-network-resources), I also get error description "the list of servers for this workgroup is not currently available" on windows 10 1903, But I can get the list on windows 10 2004 version.

Comment: @DrakeWu-MSFT Yeah, I have 19041 build and it doesn't work.

Comment: I also have OS build 19041.208, and the sample works for me. Did you get any error message when run the sample? And also check if you have [Start the "Function Discovery Provider Host" and "Function Discovery Resource Publication" services](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-au/windows-server/storage/file-server/troubleshoot/smbv1-not-installed-by-default-in-windows#explorer-network-browsing)

Answer (score 1):

I am having the same problem on my Win10 laptop. The problem occurred after installing Windows updates (KB4586781, KB4580419, KB4586864, KB4577266).

I found the following solution: You should initialize the SMBv1 protocol.
For more details see https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/6f102ed1-8e76-4cb7-8dec-05714466d441/net-view-system-error-1231?forum=win10itpronetworking