# Fast and Reliable Search of Windows network for all systems IPv4 and IPv6?

Tags: sockets, winapi, winsock, arp

The various Windows API for searching the network such as `WNetEnumResource` is dog slow and unreliable.

With IPv4 the suggestion is you can loop through the subnet and send an `ARP` or `PING` request to find live systems (without firewall blocking) and from there query them for Windows specific resources.  Kind of a crummy way to have to do it but with most IPv4 subnets being relatively small, feasible.  However, with IPv6 with so many devices available, trying to `ARP` or `PING` a range seems unreasonable.

I guess you also have `WINS` or `Active Directory` which may have computers in them, but in AD they may no longer exist and only contain systems that have joined a domain.

While I know this general question has been asked, I've not found that a good answer has ever been given.  Has this been addressed and is there a reliable fast way today, in 2021, to get a list of all active systems on the network using C/C++ especially with IPv6 growing?   If so, what is it and is there sample code?

TIA!!

Here's the sample requested with names changed:

```
NETRESOURCE[0] Scope: all resources
NETRESOURCE[0] Type: any
NETRESOURCE[0] DisplayType: network
NETRESOURCE[0] Usage: 0x80000002 = container
NETRESOURCE[0] Localname: (null)
NETRESOURCE[0] Remotename: Microsoft Terminal Services
NETRESOURCE[0] Comment: (null)
NETRESOURCE[0] Provider: Microsoft Terminal Services

NETRESOURCE[1] Scope: all resources
NETRESOURCE[1] Type: any
NETRESOURCE[1] DisplayType: network
NETRESOURCE[1] Usage: 0x80000002 = container
NETRESOURCE[1] Localname: (null)
NETRESOURCE[1] Remotename: Microsoft Windows Network
NETRESOURCE[1] Comment: (null)
NETRESOURCE[1] Provider: Microsoft Windows Network

NETRESOURCE[0] Scope: all resources
NETRESOURCE[0] Type: any
NETRESOURCE[0] DisplayType: domain
NETRESOURCE[0] Usage: 0x2 = container
NETRESOURCE[0] Localname: (null)
NETRESOURCE[0] Remotename: DOMAINXX
NETRESOURCE[0] Comment: (null)
NETRESOURCE[0] Provider: Microsoft Windows Network

NETRESOURCE[0] Scope: all resources
NETRESOURCE[0] Type: any
NETRESOURCE[0] DisplayType: server
NETRESOURCE[0] Usage: 0x2 = container
NETRESOURCE[0] Localname: (null)
NETRESOURCE[0] Remotename: \\XXX03
NETRESOURCE[0] Comment:
NETRESOURCE[0] Provider: Microsoft Windows Network

NETRESOURCE[0] Scope: all resources
NETRESOURCE[0] Type: disk
NETRESOURCE[0] DisplayType: share
NETRESOURCE[0] Usage: 0x1 = connectable
NETRESOURCE[0] Localname: (null)
NETRESOURCE[0] Remotename: \\XXX03\vmshare
NETRESOURCE[0] Comment: VM Share for VirtualBox running VirtualPC machines.
NETRESOURCE[0] Provider: Microsoft Windows Network

NETRESOURCE[2] Scope: all resources
NETRESOURCE[2] Type: any
NETRESOURCE[2] DisplayType: network
NETRESOURCE[2] Usage: 0x80000002 = container
NETRESOURCE[2] Localname: (null)
NETRESOURCE[2] Remotename: Web Client Network
NETRESOURCE[2] Comment: (null)
NETRESOURCE[2] Provider: Web Client Network

WnetOpenEnum failed with error 1222
EnumerateFunc returned FALSE
```

Pic of browse and one of actually entering the \server on the quick access bar
[image: Network Browse]
[image: UNC Entered]

Note there are a couple of other servers too.

Comment: *The various Windows API for searching the network such as WNetEnumResource is dog slow and unreliable.* Did you use [Enumerating Network Resources](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/wnet/enumerating-network-resources). Could you share what specific issue you encountered when using these APIs?

Comment: Yes, that is similar to network neighborhood, it can take a while to open and missing all kinds of systems and servers.  In fact the test only shows my local system and the domain, yet I can still access all the other servers and devices by using \\servername from explorer or command prompt.

Comment: What exactly does *unreliable* mean? Are you experiencing the same problem as [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64170649/wnetopenenum-does-not-return-anything-after-root-level) in using the win32 sample? Did you get any error?

Comment: It's been unreliable all the way back to Win9x, it routinely didn't list all the computers on the network. You'd have to monkey around with the master browser and such depending on which system got it.  I would have it setup to get to any domain and system across multiple states, but didn't always work.   But yes, now using Win10 SMBV2 and only see my local machine. No servers, but can still \\servername to get to it.  Right now I just need reliability on the local network.

Comment: So, does the resource displayed in File Explorer > Network is different as the resource enumerated by `WNetEnumResource()`?

Comment: no, it doesn't work. It used to show everything but NAS and Linux devices (which are using SMB) but now it doesn't show anything but the local system.   Maybe the SMBV2 change?  But I'm talking in general for a program to work it needs something reliable, pings work if no firewall blocking, but with IPv6 maybe too many, from there query for the shares and such, but seems it should just work.  Does MS network browsing not work with SMBv2?

Comment: Maybe you can share a result's screenshot of the `WNetEnumResource` sample, File Explorer > Network and `\\servername`. So that I can help to submit this issue to relevant internal engineers.

Comment: okay, where do I send it?

Comment: You can share it in this post. Be careful to avoid private information.

Comment: I added them to the original post with names blocked out.

Comment: I was testing for the last hour and out of about 50 times I pull it up, once it actually had the other missing server.  But next try they were already missing again.